# AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification not called for LIVE

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am trying to playback Live audio stream in m3u8 format on iOS. The problem is `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` is never called once the live audio stream is ended. After further investigation I came to know that the live stream doesn't have the `duration` and that might be the reason it doesn't know when to trigger `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`.

**Is there any solution to this, so I could know when my live event is ended?**

Comment: Add the observer AFTER play() method. And remove it before pause().

Answer (score -1):

Use audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying delegate i think its work for you.

Comment: That is a different delegate not used with `AVPlayer`.

Comment: Then you need to use KVO observer.